# How to manage time complexity while working with array comparision using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need some help. here I am comparing the array's one value with next value using for loop in JavaScript but for long array its taking too much time. I am explaining my code below.

```
const data = [1,2,3,4,5....1000]
let compareArr = [];
for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    for(let j=i+1;j<data.length;j++) {
        compareArr.push(data[i] & data[j]);
    }

}
console.log(compareArr)
```

Here I am using the bitwise AND operator to compare within values one one array but for small length array its ok but if the array length is more than 100 it its taking too much time so here my concern is in which way I can reduce the time complexity of the execution.

Comment: Why do you need a nested for loop in the first place? You just want to compare for example element 1 with element 2? thats it? or also every other element?

Comment: I don't think it *can* be reduced. You are creating the product of each item with every other item, so that's `O(n!)` complexity *and* produces `n!` results.

Comment: @Aaron: Here  I need to compare with each element with its all next elements.

Comment: how is `compareArr` used? the first compare value for item 2 in the list will be at compareArr[data.length], correct? and the first compare value for item 3 will be at compareArr[data.length*2-1] ?  seems awkward

Comment: @VLAZ is right, if you are definetly in need of doing comparison with each subsequent element, the time complexity is O(n!), hence you cant reduce time. Not too sure if you should use a script in a different language that maybe supports caching. So when 2 elements were compared before, there is no calculation

Comment: @Aaron you can also use a memoized function in JS. Whether that would be useful is another matter, of course.

Comment: Wow didnt know that, thanks! @VLAZ I'd all suggest that OP gives us some background about his general problem and why he needs to compare all values. Maybe this gives another view on that.

Comment: if the data is used sparsely it would probably be faster to just compute the bitwise AND at the time it's needed for a particular pair rather than computing all of them up front

Comment: could you show, source data as text and desired result as text?